# How to represent the ceiling function using mathematical notation?

Tags: functions, notation

How to represent the ceiling function using mathematical notation?

I need an equation to input in a program because it doesn't except the ceiling function so it has to be some sort of mathematical equation. I also can't convert decimal numbers to integers within the string.

I know the floor function can be represented mathematically most simply as "x-x mod 1" or using an arctan equation but is there something similar to these mathematical formats for the ceiling function?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Note that $\lceil x\rceil = -\lfloor -x\rfloor$.

Comment: this looks like something i may be able to work with but i'm having trouble with the expression i'm using. floor = x - frac(x) and ceil = -{-floor}.....how would the -floor expression be written?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. This works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried my hand at writing one; I'd be interested to hear what you think. Assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

$$\lfloor x \rfloor:=\sup\{n\,\big\vert\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\quad n\leq x\}$$

$$\lceil x \rceil:=\inf\{n\,\big\vert\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\quad n\geq x\}$$

Comment: This looks like it works in terms of the relationship. But for programming purposes, as you can see, somehow this relationship has to be expressed in mathematical operators and functions accepted by the programming code bu thanks!

Comment: @xmlnube That's what I was thinking. It made me wonder if there's a way of programming $\sup$ and $\inf$ in some language. It seems like you could but I really wouldn't know how. Some kind of sorting algorithm perhaps :)